# Docker pull error AWS ECR "unauthorized: authentication required"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I logged in to AWS ECR repo and fired pull command but giving this error

```
# $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
Login Succeeded

# docker pull 432354543235.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/abc-example:1.1.1                                        
Pulling repository 432354543235.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/abc-example:1.1.1
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Comment: I would check the region used to get the token and see if it matches with the repository region.

Comment: @QasimSarfraz, yes I already checked that and it matches with the region

Comment: Do you have any polices defined for the repository? Or may be something wrong with $HOME/.docker/config.json ?

Comment: After Qasim Sarfraz ' recommendation I removed old auth entry from $HOME/.docker/config.json and it worked. I had same problem with you, after login command auth keys are being updated on config.json but still some older entries resides there.

Answer (score 7):

Amazon have [well documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html#registry_auth) how to use the AWS CLI to allow docker to authenticate to an Amazon ECR registry.

However, `get-login` has now been [deprecated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html). You will need to use `get-login-password` instead.

They note in their documentation that you can pass the authentication token to the docker login command. You will need to specify the Amazon ECR registry URI you want to authenticate to as well.

For example

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 \
  | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin \
  123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I can then pull the image according to `registry/repository[:tag]`.

[Registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html) is a combination of your Account ID and the regional ECR endpoint, e.g:

```
123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

[Repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Repositories.html) is the name of the place to store images e.g:

```
myrepo
```

[Tag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-using-tags.html) is the usual image metadata, e.g.: `latest`

Below is a complete example of authenticating and pulling an image:

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-southeast-2 \
  | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin \
  123456789012.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

$ docker pull 123456789012.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/myrepo:latest
latest: Pulling from myrepo
5bed26d33875: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:aabbccdd
Status: Downloaded newer image for 123456789012.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/myrepo:latest
123456789012.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/myrepo:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

> aws ecr get-login --no-include-email

This only prints the login command.You need to execute the login command returned by this call.

Try this

> eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)